# Помогите разобраться с задачей

Tags: c++

Задание было такое: 
Создать класс для работы сo строками. Разработать элементы класса:

1. Поля:

   - указатель на char - хранит адрес динамически выделенной памяти;
   - int n.
2. Конструктор, позволяющий создать строку из n символов.
3. Методы, позволяющие:

   - подсчитать количество знаков препинания в строке;
   - заменить в строке все строчные символы на прописные;
   - прочитать  символ из заданной позиции.
4. Свойства:

   - возвращающее общее количество элементов в строке (доступное только для чтения);
   - позволяющее установить значение поля, в соответствии с введенным значением строки с клавиатуры, а также получить значение данного поля (доступно для чтения и записи).

В конструкторе, который принимает укатель на char, не проставляется терминирующий ноль. Во втором конструкторе, терминирующий ноль проставляется в неправильно место (должен проставляться в n-й символ).
Как это сделать в данном коде?

```
class String
{
public:
  String(char* string = "")
  {
    n = strlen(string) + 1;
    str = new char[n];
    memcpy(str, string, n);
  }

  String(char* string, size_t size)  //конструктор позволяющий создать строку из size символов
  {
    n = size + 1;
    str = new char[n];      
    memcpy(str, string, n * sizeof(char));
    str[size] = 0;
  }

  ~String()
  {
    if (str)
      delete str;
  }

  void print()
  {
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
  }

  int const getnum() //количество символов в строке
  {
    return n - 1;
  }

  char const getchar(int n) // символ из позиции n
  {
    return str[n - 1];
  }

  void upper()  // верхний регистр
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        str[i] = toupper(str[i]);
  }

  int const punctuation() // количество знаков припинания
  {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      if (ispunct(str[i]))
        count++;
    return count;
  }

private:
  char* str;
  int n; 
};


int main()
{
  String str("I!love!!!programming!");

  str.upper();
  str.print();

  std::cout << str.getnum() << std::endl;
  std::cout << str.punctuation() << std::endl;
  std::cout << str.getchar(1) << std::endl;

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: В деструкторе должно быть `delete [] str`

Answer (score 1):

используйте strcpy в первом и strncpy во втором. нуль всегда где надо и параметров меньше.